# How to copy privileges from one primary user token to another?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, kernel32

My goal is to copy [privileges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716(v=vs.85).aspx) from one *primary user token* to another before I start a user mode process with the destination token. I created a sample pseudo code to illustrate what I need to accomplish.

The following will be run from a local system service:

```
//dwSessionId = user session ID to run process in

HANDLE hToken1 = NULL;      //Source user token
WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, &hToken1);

HANDLE hSelfToken = NULL;   //User token for system service
HANDLE hToken2 = NULL;      //Adjusted self-token

OpenProcessToken(::GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hSelfToken);
DuplicateTokenEx(hSelfToken, TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, 
    NULL, SecurityIdentification, TokenPrimary, &hToken2);

//Specify user session to run in
SetTokenInformation(hToken2, TokenSessionId, &dwSessionId, sizeof(dwSessionId));

//Now I need to set privileges in 'hToken2' as they are in 'hToken1'
...

//Then use 'hToken2' in CreateProcessAsUser() to start a process
```

Any idea how to copy privileges from `hToken1` to `hToken2`?

Comment: Why can't you just create the process using `hToken1` ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I tried it but then `CreateProcessAsUser` succeeds but the user process never starts and I get its exit code set to `STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED` or `0xC0000142`

Comment: It is certainly possible to use `CreateProcessAsUser` with `hToken1` and it would be a lot safer - unless you're trying to launch the process on the secure desktop?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: What would happen in a secure desktop? You mean `Winlogon` right?

Comment: IIRC the secure desktop is named Winlogon, yes, and I gather that processes running in the user's context can't use it (hence "secure").  I'm not familiar with the details.  But that's the only reason I can think of why using `hToken1` might not be possible.  If that's not what you're doing, then you really should use `hToken1` - if you post an MCVE (as a separate question) I expect we can figure out what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to obtain `hToken2` from `hToken`, and then use it in `CreateProcessAsUser`. There is no need to use `hSelfToken`, actually.

```
HANDLE GetAdjustedToken(HANDLE hSrcToken)
{
    TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN admin = {};
    HANDLE hTarToken = 0;
    DWORD dw = 0;
    if (GetTokenInformation(hSrcToken, (TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS)TokenLinkedToken, &admin, sizeof(TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN), &dw))
    {
        hTarToken = admin.LinkedToken;
    }
    else
    {
        DuplicateTokenEx(hSrcToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, SecurityIdentification, TokenPrimary, &hTarToken);
    }
    return hTarToken;
}
```

And if you want to create the new process at a low mandatory integrity level, see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625960.aspx) MSDN article.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what it does? Especially the call with `TokenLinkedToken`?

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2013/03/22/how-to-launch-a-process-as-a-full-administrator-when-uac-is-enabled.aspx

Comment: Oh, I see. `TokenLinkedToken` retrieves an administrative token. Well, the point of my exercise here is to actually reduce privileges and not escalate them. If I run it like I showed above my user process runs with a set of SYSTEM privileges, which I DO NOT want.

Comment: Sorry for mistaking your use case. So you want this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625960.aspx

Comment: No, this is not about `mandatory integrity level`. I'm asking about `token privileges`. Those are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to call `GetTokenInformation` using `TokenPrivileges` class for your original token to obtain `TOKEN_PRIVILEGES` structure. Then call `AdjustTokenPrivileges` with it to update your cloned token. You will have to call `GetTokenInformation` twice - first one to obtain buffer length and second - to get actual data.

```
HANDLE hSelfToken = NULL;   //User token for system service
HANDLE hToken2 = NULL;      //Adjusted self-token

OpenProcessToken(::GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hSelfToken);
DuplicateTokenEx(hSelfToken, TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS,
    NULL, SecurityIdentification, TokenPrimary, &hToken2);

PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES pPriv = NULL;
DWORD dwLen = 0;
GetTokenInformation(hSelfToken, TokenPrivileges, (LPVOID)pPriv, 0, &dwLen);
if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    return(0);

pPriv = (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwLen);
if (!GetTokenInformation(hSelfToken, TokenPrivileges, (LPVOID)pPriv, dwLen, &dwLen))
    return(0);

AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken2, FALSE, pPriv, dwLen, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the `GetTokenInformation` and `AdjustTokenPrivileges` API. But your code sample is totally wrong. You can't do it with just one call to `AdjustTokenPrivileges`

Comment: Why? MSDN clearly tells that you could adjust multiple token privileges with just one `AdjustTokenPrivileges` call. My test example is also not reporting any errors.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: No, it can actually remove them as well. Wouldn't `SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED` flag in a privilege's attribute do it?

Comment: @Ari0nhh: The goal is to reduce privileges in the destination token (or `hToken2`) so your example will take a full set of SYSTEM privileges from `hSelfToken` and apply it to destination token `hToken2`.

Comment: In your question you write that goal is - copying original token privileges to the new one. There is nothing in question text about reducing.

Comment: Yes, I'd misread the question.  But keep in mind even with the privileges disabled, the local system account is still administrative and can, e.g., create and start a system service in order to get the privileges back.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: What if I remove most privileges? The target process will not be able to add them back to self later, will it?

Comment: @Ari0nhh: Picture situation when the destination token has more privileges than the source token. Your method will not handle this situation correctly.

Comment: I just tried it and using the `SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED` attribute on existing privileges in the call to `AdjustTokenPrivileges` I was able to remove all privileges, except `SeSystemtimePrivilege`. For some reason it stayed. The issue is actually how to add privileges back to token? I don't know of any means to do it. So the method should probably be in removing only those privileges that are not present in the source token ... but that would not always produce an exact copy of privileges.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I might have gotten something close to what I needed. It's not really copying privileges, but for the purpose of "stripping out" privileges I can create a restricted token that will have almost all privileges removed (except `SeChangeNotifyPrivilege` and `SeSystemtimePrivilege`.)

```
//Call the following instead of DuplicateTokenEx() in my example above
CreateRestrictedToken(hSelfToken, DISABLE_MAX_PRIVILEGE,
            0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL,
            &hToken2);
```

FYI: Just a curious fact. For some reason I was not able to remove the `SeSystemtimePrivilege` from the token. Not with this method, nor using `AdjustTokenPrivileges` with its attribute set to `SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED`. All other privileges could be removed just fine, except this one. So if anyone have any idea why, I'd be glad to learn it?